# Apache Camel camel-openapi-java Schema Definitions not generating correctly

Tags: java, apache-camel, openapi

I am running into an issue in Apache Camel where the POJOs I define in my RestDefinition *type* and *outType* are not generating correctly in my openapi schema. When I swap back to the older camel-swagger-java component, my schema is generating with all object definitions correctly, however this is in swagger v2 not openapi v3 which is why i am moving to this component.

Is there anything I am missing here to get this generating correctly for camel-openapi-java?

Dependency versions:

camel / camel-openapi-java   = v 3.4.3

Sample Classes:

```
public class RequestBean {

    private int propertyA;
    private boolean propertyB;

    public int getPropertyA() {
        return propertyA;
    }

    public void setPropertyA(int propertyA) {
        this.propertyA = propertyA;
    }

    public boolean isPropertyB() {
        return propertyB;
    }

    public void setPropertyB(boolean propertyB) {
        this.propertyB = propertyB;
    }
}
```

```
public class JavaBean {
    private String propertyA;
    private String propertyB;
    private int propertyC;

    public String getPropertyA() {
        return propertyA;
    }

    public void setPropertyA(String propertyA) {
        this.propertyA = propertyA;
    }

    public String getPropertyB() {
        return propertyB;
    }

    public void setPropertyB(String propertyB) {
        this.propertyB = propertyB;
    }

    public int getPropertyC() {
        return propertyC;
    }

    public void setPropertyC(int propertyC) {
        this.propertyC = propertyC;
    }
}
```

Rest Configuration and Definition:

```
 restConfiguration()
                .apiComponent("openapi")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .apiContextPath("api-doc")
                .apiProperty("api.title", "Test Camel Service")
                .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0")
                .apiProperty("cors", "true");




        rest()
                .path("/test")
                .description("Test Path")
                .post("testPost").id("testPost").consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .type(RequestBean.class)
                .outType(JavaBean.class)
             .to("direct:a");
```

Generated schema:

```
{
  "openapi" : "3.0.2",
  "info" : {
    "title" : "Test Camel Service",
    "version" : "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers" : [ {
    "url" : ""
  } ],
  "paths" : {
    "/test/testPost" : {
      "post" : {
        "requestBody" : {
          "description" : "",
          "content" : {
            "application/json" : {
              "schema" : {
                "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/RequestBean"
              }
            }
          },
          "required" : true
        },
        "tags" : [ "test" ],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "content" : {
              "application/json" : {
                "schema" : {
                  "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/JavaBean"
                }
              }
            },
            "description" : "Output type"
          }
        },
        "operationId" : "testPost",
        "x-camelContextId" : "camel-1",
        "x-routeId" : "testPost"
      }
    }
  },
  "components" : {
    "schemas" : {
      "RequestBean" : {
        "type" : "RequestBean",
        "x-className" : {
          "format" : "com.example.test.RequestBean",
          "type" : "string"
        }
      },
      "JavaBean" : {
        "type" : "JavaBean",
        "x-className" : {
          "format" : "com.example.test.JavaBean",
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "tags" : [ {
    "name" : "test",
    "description" : "Test Path"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Can you put together a sample project that reproduces this? And maybe put it together as a zip file and create a JIRA ticket and attach the zip at Apache Camel about this bug, or put the sample project on github etc. Its much easier to have something that demonstrates the bug that we can use to track down and fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Claus, I will do this as soon as I have a chance.

Comment: I just stumbled across the exact same issue while experimenting with camel. @ClausIbsen should this actually work?

Comment: Btw: one can use https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core to generate correct type declarations

Comment: Hi Claus, I created a JIRA ticket here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-15503

Comment: @languitar have you found a way of getting the type declarations working with the camel-openapi-java component using the library you mentioned above?

Comment: @sleepy_penguin no, that would mean patching the component